# Cycle a Rust iterator a given number of times

Tags: rust, iterator, cycle

How do I cycle through an iterator a finite number of times?

I would expect the output of something like this to be `1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3` and then stop:

```
vec![1, 2, 3].iter().cycle(4)
//                         ^ but .cycle() doesn't take an argument...
```

I don't know the length of the iterator to begin with.

Comment: That would be a nice addition to [itertools](https://docs.rs/itertools/).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One simple way is to repeat the iterator itself, take the first 4 and flatten:

```rust
fn main() {
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let res = std::iter::repeat(v.iter())
        .take(4)
        .flatten()
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    dbg!(res);
}
```

---

Some micro-benchmark result using code in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/edwardw/e42c50b6fa1c9112b6fff282835341ba) comparing 3 different approaches:

- repeat-take-flatten in this answer
- hand-rolled loop
- a `cycle_n` implementation mimicking `Iterator::cycle`.

Kudos to `rustc`, `cycle_n` consistently outperforms the other two when the input is reasonably large whereas repeat-take-flatten performs the best for small input.

[image: Micro-benchmark between repeat-take-flatten, hand-rolled loop and <code>cycle_n</code>]

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios [godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/5So5hQ), can't tell if it is well optimized or not :D

Comment: @edwardw Compared to a hand-rolled loop: https://godbolt.org/z/GRbTt7

Comment: @phimuemue several hundred lines of assembly are still too much for a mortal like me to decipher LOL. Did some micro-benchmark.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such an iterator in the std lib.

If you know the iterator size, you can `take` your number times the size of the iterator:

```
fn cycle_n_times<T: Clone>(slice: &[T], count: usize) -> impl Iterator<Item = &T> {
    slice.iter().cycle().take(slice.len() * count)
}
```

Or you can write your own that is more general:

```
pub struct Ncycles<I> {
    orig: I,
    iter: I,
    count: usize,
}

impl<I: Clone> Ncycles<I> {
    fn new(iter: I, count: usize) -> Ncycles<I> {
        Ncycles {
            orig: iter.clone(),
            iter,
            count,
        }
    }
}

impl<I> Iterator for Ncycles<I>
where
    I: Clone + Iterator,
{
    type Item = <I as Iterator>::Item;

    #[inline]
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<<I as Iterator>::Item> {
        match self.iter.next() {
            None if self.count == 0 => None,
            None => {
                self.iter = self.orig.clone();
                self.count -= 1;
                self.iter.next()
            }
            y => y,
        }
    }
}

#[test]
fn it_work() {
    Ncycles::new(vec![1, 2, 3].iter(), 4).eq(&[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]);
}
```

Comment: Collecting into a slice first seems reasonable to me, given that we are going to need the elements multiple times. It's also the only solution that works when your iterator is not `Clone`, e.g. an iterator over the lines of a file.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Yes, if I had to optimize the code in this situation, I would benchmark this.

Answer (score 0):

One could leverage [`slice::repeat`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.repeat), but I can't imagine this is very efficient:

```
let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
let it = v.iter();
println!("{:?}", it.map(|x| *x).collect::<Vec<i32>>().repeat(4).iter());
```